# change mulitple columns in a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I have a list of 12 dataframes. they all have the same structure. 
one of them look tat way: 
(there 9 in each dataframes, last one can't be shown here)

```
X2016_kvish_1_10t
    kvish keta maslul yom nefah                date day_mean day_min
1       1   10      1   1  1710 2016-09-11 00:00:00 2848.375     588
2       1   10      1   1   934 2016-09-11 01:00:00 2848.375     588
3       1   10      1   1   800 2016-09-11 02:00:00 2848.375     588
4       1   10      1   1   637 2016-09-11 03:00:00 2848.375     588
5       1   10      1   1   588 2016-09-11 04:00:00 2848.375     588
6       1   10      1   1   951 2016-09-11 05:00:00 2848.375     588
7       1   10      1   1  2312 2016-09-11 06:00:00 2848.375     588
8       1   10      1   1  3769 2016-09-11 07:00:00 2848.375     588
9       1   10      1   1  3348 2016-09-11 08:00:00 2848.375     588
10      1   10      1   1  2788 2016-09-11 09:00:00 2848.375     588
11      1   10      1   1  2879 2016-09-11 10:00:00 2848.375     588
12      1   10      1   1  3318 2016-09-11 11:00:00 2848.375     588
13      1   10      1   1  3713 2016-09-11 12:00:00 2848.375     588
14      1   10      1   1  4102 2016-09-11 13:00:00 2848.375     588
15      1   10      1   1  4333 2016-09-11 14:00:00 2848.375     588
16      1   10      1   1  4583 2016-09-11 15:00:00 2848.375     588
17      1   10      1   1  4614 2016-09-11 16:00:00 2848.375     588
18      1   10      1   1  4367 2016-09-11 17:00:00 2848.375     588
19      1   10      1   1  4040 2016-09-11 18:00:00 2848.375     588
20      1   10      1   1  3766 2016-09-11 19:00:00 2848.375     588
21      1   10      1   1  3443 2016-09-11 20:00:00 2848.375     588
22      1   10      1   1  2793 2016-09-11 21:00:00 2848.375     588
23      1   10      1   1  2439 2016-09-11 22:00:00 2848.375     588
24      1   10      1   1  2134 2016-09-11 23:00:00 2848.375     588
25      1   10      1   2  1317 2016-09-12 00:00:00 2818.042     660
26      1   10      1   2   759 2016-09-12 01:00:00 2818.042     660
27      1   10      1   2   727 2016-09-12 02:00:00 2818.042     660
28      1   10      1   2   660 2016-09-12 03:00:00 2818.042     660
#...
#168 rows total
```

I built a vector of numburs so I can change my 7's columns (the **day_mean** column) in each dataframe so it will get new values of NA. so I used this function to apply it :

```
aa = seq(1, 168 , 24) # the numeric vector
bb = rep(T, 168)
bb[aa] = FALSE
cc= (which(bb))

function(X) { # the function that cahnge my 7's column in each dataframe
X[,7][cc] = NA   

return(X)
}

lapply(kvish_1_10t.tables, func)
```

So far everything is well, but when Im trying to apply the same function on multiple columns, Its send me an error. I changed the function so it reffer to additional columns as I wrote down here.

```
function(X) { 
X[,7:9][cc] = NA

return(x)
{

 Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, cc, value = NA) : 
 new columns would leave holes after existing columns
```

Comment: what if you change `X[,7:9][cc] = NA` to `X[cc,7:9] = NA`?

Comment: It seems to me like your "order" or subsetting the list is wrong. The first element is always the number or name of the list. The second `[]` can subset the data.frame/matrix - provided this list item is a data.frame/matrix

Comment: I tried this but It shows me an error:   ` Error in `*tmp*`[[j]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2 `